# Android emulator not processing http get request, but iOS simulator works fine

Tags: android, http, flutter, dart

**What I am trying to do:** fetch data using google map api, then pass data to the next screen.

**What's wrong:** it works fine on iOS simulator, it manages to get to the next screen and populate the map with the data (prints position, "yay", http status code, and the "loopyays"). But on android emulator, it prints only position and "yay", and hangs there, does not navigate to the next screen.

What went wrong? :/ Please help me out..

```
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  void getUserLocation() async {
    try {
      Position position = await Geolocator()
          .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
      print(position);
      Set<Marker> markers = {};
      String url =
          'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${position.latitude},${position.longitude}&maxprice=4&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=AIzaSyDVzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      print('yay');
      http.Response data = await http.get(url);
      print(data.statusCode);
      var resultList = jsonDecode(data.body)['results'];
      for (Map i in resultList) {
        var coords = (i['geometry']['location']);
        print('loopyay');
        markers.add(Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(i['name']),
            position: LatLng(coords['lat'], coords['lng'])));
      }

      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return UserLocationScreen(
          userLocation: position,
          markers: markers,
        );
      }));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

**my config**

1. I have `androidmapsdk` activated on my google console
2. in my androidmanifest I have this after the

```xml
< meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyDVzbjC2hViOnxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

3. in my build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        }
```

4. in my gradle.properties

```
    android.enableJetifier=true
    android.useAndroidX=true
    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

Comment: Does your androidManfifest.xml file contain `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/45940861/7666442

Comment: Are you using Android 9 pie?

Comment: Why are you using the web API and not the Google Maps Android SDK?

Comment: @Muldec yes it does

Comment: @HarshPanchal, yes i am using android 9

Comment: @nasch, oh may I ask what's the diff? I'm new to this

Comment: @nasch do you mean i should be using: flutter_google_places instead?

Comment: No I mean there's a built-in SDK for Google Maps in Android so you don't have to bother with making HTTP calls yourself.  Does it not include the functionality you need?

Answer (score 5):

In Android 9 pie, http request is not permitted in default.

Solution:
Please update this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file like below.

```
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        ... // Your current code.

    </application>
```

Have a good day.